# Why are there multiple client secrets for each azure client id?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

As I understand it, the idea is that azure allows the registration of multiple applications (client ids) each with multiple *secrets*.

I (think that I) get the part of multiple applications registrations, since each app would get ***fine-grained access control***.

The question then is why would it be possible to create `multiple (client) secrets for the same application (client) id`?

Don't all the secrets provide **the exact same access** (since they are all bound to the same application/client id)?

Why would someone need even a second (client) secret?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, all secrets have the same access as they are similar to passwords for a user.

The point is that secrets expire, and having more than one allows you to rotate them.

1. Before secret 1 expires, create new secret 2
2. Update application with secret 2
3. Remove secret 1

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the use case. `A side question` arising is whether there is a way to programmatically trigger the rotation flow you described (create new secret, then revoke old)`?` Something like `certbot` does with `lets Encrypt` close to certificate expiration datetime.

Comment: Never mind. Found some info in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/register-application-cli-rest#add-a-client-secret-for-confidential-client-applications). Then I (assume that I) would just have to write a small shell script to get the desired `certbot-like` functionality.

Comment: At least one option that comes to mind is that you can put the client secrets in Key Vault and set the expiry for the secret equal to the expiry in Azure AD. Then you can get Event Grid events when those are close to expiry. You can then react to it by creating a new secret and adding that as a new version on the secret in Key Vault. You don't necessarily have to delete the old secret at this point as the app might not have refreshed the new version yet.

Comment: Great, thanks. That seems more interesting as I will get my hand on Key Vault.